# sql question how to get the last 10 rows added, or edited?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `notas`
Then it is...

```
create table notas
(
idnota int primary key identity,
nombre varchar(50),
texto text,
fprogramada datetime
)
```

How do I select the last 10? But do not forget that user can add 20 notes and delete 
note with id=19, delete note with id=15...

Then the query must return:

- 20
- 18
- 17
- 16
- 14
- 13
- 12
- 11
- 10
- 9

And if he edited note with id=3 then query must return:

- 3
- 20
- 18
- 17
- 16
- 14
- 13
- 12
- 11
- 10

How should I write this query? Preferably as a single query.

Date... fprogramada is not the date created, or eddited, if not it is the date than user want this note... for example
i come i open my program, and i want to anote a note...
"go with dentist" fprograma= 15-04-2011 it refers "go with dentist" will be on friday...

Comment: The syntax is very different between the two databases (and not the ANSI `FETCH FIRST x ROWS ONLY` either)...

Comment: @OMG thanks i didnt know i am a student...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new column in your table that holds the `datetime` when row was last modified.

```
create table notas
(
idnota int primary key identity,
nombre varchar(50),
texto text,
fprogramada datetime,
Modified datetime
)
```

Then you query 10 latest modified like this.

```
select top 10 *
from notas
order by Modified desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from notas order by idnota desc limit 10
```

will return the last rows added, for editing, you need to maintain a column for edit time and update it with every edit, perhaps thats what fprogramada is, i don't know! Once you have that, just order by that instead of ID

I just saw it has both mysql and sql server tag, if it's ms sql server you need select top 10 instead, mysql is limit 10

Comment: i am from mexico sorry, fprograma = fecha programa in english it means "programmated date"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fprogramada` contains the date a particular record was updated, then

```
select top 10 * from notas order by fprogramada desc
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM notas ORDER BY fprogamada DESC` if you are using T-SQL